# Django 'django-admin' command not found. django version : 2.2

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use the django-admin but sadly its not working correctly and I must use `python -m django`
how can i fix it
the commandline exception that it gives:

```
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ django-admin version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: If `python -m django` works, then I would use that, and not worry too much about getting `django-admin` working. You usually only use `django-admin` once to run `startproject`, and then switch to `manage.py` after that.

Comment: Thanks alot man :)

Answer (score 1):

Use virtual env for working with python and Django projects, you can install it from [this](https://pypi.org/project/pyenv/) site. After activating the virtual env, install Django and run it:

```
python -m pip install Django
django-admin startproject mysite
```

Go to the site directory and run the app:

```
py manage.py run server.
```

From here you can read the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/) and follow the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Arch. The way to fix it is to install the package as a root `sudo pip install django`.